# how to extract director name from each row in dataset['crew']

Tags: python, data-science, recommendation-engine

"[{'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f49', 'department': 'Directing', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7879, 'job': 'Director', 'name': 'John Lasseter', 'profile_path': '/7EdqiNbr4FRjIhKHyPPdFfEEEFG.jpg'}
]"" the dataset['crew'] looks like this.

Comment: @deadshot You can't use json.loads() for this string as it's not valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You have a string representation of a list of dictionaries. There is only one dictionary in the list. Therefore:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "[{'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f49', 'department': 'Directing', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7879, 'job': 'Director', 'name': 'John Lasseter', 'profile_path': '/7EdqiNbr4FRjIhKHyPPdFfEEEFG.jpg'} ]"

for d in literal_eval(s):
    print(d['name'])
```

**Output:**

```
John Lasseter
```

**Note:**

Using the *for* loop allows for more than one dictionary in the list